# hidden module when debug with ollydbg 2.01 with size?

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg

i try reversing program with ollydbg2.01, but i Noticed strange thing with ollydbg when try debug program in log file i have `76FC0000 Module <Mod_76FC>(anonymous)` and when press `alt+E` i have size ??? and type `hidden`.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the .exe with us?

Comment: exe is just the test.exe that come with ollydbg2.01

Comment: i upload file here http://www60.zippyshare.com/v/N5mZSVI0/file.html

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing with the `test.exe` that comes with OllyDbg 2.01. Are you using any OllyDbg plugins, and do you have any special security software installed?

Comment: first i have ollyext with olly and i thought problem from ollyext so i remove it but even without plugin i still see this problem, i'm not have any special security software installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is not _from_ OllyDbg or `test.exe`, but rather from some other software you have installed. If you're confident that it's not from a security package, then it could be a usermode rootkit. You might want to scan your system and see if anything interesting is found.

Comment: i scan my system with gmer, Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit, TDSSKiller utility from kaspersk and kaspersky antivirus and no rootkit or malware is detect

Comment: What happens when you try to look at the memory at those base addresses?

Comment: it seem their nothing, when i try to Doubleclick on address nothing happen also when press `Ctrl+G ` and write address or write Mod_76FC no result, i  noticed in log window when right click -> flow in cpu dump,  no result in cpu window but hex dump go to first at  MZ